# HTACCESS repeats url twice

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Hi Am having this little problem with .HTACCESS HTTPS redirection

> Not Found
>
> The requested URL /limoamerican/limoamerican/limofleet.php was not found on this server.
>
> Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Any help is appreciated

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]


Options -Multiviews
Options +FollowSymLinks


#LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so 
#AddModule mod_rewrite.c

RewriteBase /

#RewriteRule    ^geo/United-States/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$  ijt.php?state=$1&city=$2  [NC,L]

#RewriteRule    ^geo/United-States/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$  rxm.php?state=$1&city=$2  [NC,L]

RewriteRule    ^geo/United-States/NY/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$  mxt.php?city=$1  [NC,L]
RewriteRule    ^geo/United-States/CT/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$  ijt.php?city=$1  [NC,L]
RewriteRule    ^geo/United-States/NJ/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$  rxm.php?city=$1  [NC,L]
```

Comment: Tank you Brett, If I type directly https://www.limoamerican.com in location bar works fine. But when I click link on Google SERP links is redirected to limoamerican.com/limoamerican/limofleet.php. Please help

Comment: The 404 page means that script isn't there. None of your redirect rules apply to that url, so the htaccess is not the issue.

Comment: Thanks @Brett - solved it was redirection issue. Solved by changing urls from http to https